# How to generate keystore for root signed certificate?

Tags: tls, certificate-authority, openssl

I need to create keystore and truststore with root signed certificates.

I have these files (at this step they are identical for client and for server):

1. client_cert.pem
2. client_prv_key.pem
3. root_cert.pem
4. client_password lets say 12345

I will create the truststore with the client certificate.
Now I need to create keystore. I tried this:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey root_cert.pem -in client_cert.pem -out client.p12
```

This result in an error: "`unable to load private key`".

Next command, after creating the `.p12` file is (when openssl command will end successfully):

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore client.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore client.jks -deststoretype jks
```

What should be the command in order to create keystore with root-signed certificates? How should I build the `.p12` file with the root signed certificate?

Also, for mutual authentication in Java truststore is required. After trying some options the correct way to build the truststore is: (12345 is client_password which I used in all places where password was required)

`keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -keystore client_truststore.jks -storetype jks -storepass 12345 -file root_cert.pem`

Where 12345 is client_password (which I used in all places where password was required)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your filenames are accurate, so `client_cert.pem` and `client_prv_key.pem` actually contain the client cert and privatekey respectively in PEM format:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in client_cert.pem -inkey client_prv_key.pem -certfile root_cert.pem -out client.p12
# prompts for the input-key passphrase, then the output passphrase (twice)

# to specify passphrase on commandline for client_prv_key -passin pass:xyz
# similarly passphrase on commandline for the output -passout pass:xyz
# however these make the password(s) visible in ps or similar on most OSes,
# and usually visible in your shell (or CMD) history, which is often insecure
```

Alternatively you can provide them all on standard input *in correct order*:

```
cat client_prv_key.pem client_cert.pem root_cert.pem | openssl pkcs12 -export -out client.p12
# same options for passphrase
```

PS- do NOT enter an empty passphrase for the PKCS12. OpenSSL lets you create it even though it's silly, but Java can't decrypt it which defeats your purpose.

Comment: Tried what you suggested. Used the same passphrase for input and output. Then I used keytool to create `.jks` file in the same way I described in my question. Put them in Java code, with the passphrase as password. I start the server and client. When sending request I get an error: `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain`. Any suggestions?

Comment: It works! I had another problem with my truststore. I will edit my question and add an explanation about this. Thanks.